# Dictionary of all words and their frequencies in the English language

Tags: dictionary

Does a free open source dictionary which will allow me to incorporate it in a commercial product exist? I'm looking for a dictionary of all English words including their frequencies in the English language and type (noun, adjective, etc.). If so, where I can find one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [this](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/wordfreq).

Comment: that's pretty amazing, and large_en.msgpack.gz only weighs 2 mb (!)

Answer (score 0):

Here are is a page that collects licence agreements for various open-source word lists:

http://www.quinapalus.com/dicts.html

Those are plain word lists - no frequencies or descriptions.

I don't know of something that actually matches what you're looking for. I'm a bit doubtful to be honest.